# Comparing strings from AdafruitIO_Data object

Tags: arduino, adafruit

I can't seem to compare what I believe are strings.

My function looks like the following:

```
void handleMessage(AdafruitIO_Data *data) {
  Serial.printf("\nreceived <- %s", data->value());
  if (data->value() == "OPEN") {
    Serial.printf("\nIt worked!");
  }
}
```

When printed, `data->value()` prints what I expect it to, but when I compare it like this `data->value() == "OPEN"` it doesn't work. What is the right way to do this, and why isn't the above working?

I have attempted to use `strcmp()` as suggested by [How do I properly compare strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings)

```
void handleMessage(AdafruitIO_Data *data) {
  Serial.printf("\nreceived <- %s", data->value());
  if (strcmp(data->value() == "OPEN")) {
    Serial.printf("\nIt worked!");
  }
}
```

However I get:

```
FileName:48: error: cannot convert 'bool' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int strcmp(const char*, const char*)'
```

It isn't a boolean when it is printed. From my example it prints: `received <- OPEN`

Comment: @MFisherKDX I had seen/tried was that too, but that also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: post the definition of `AdafruitIO_Data` and how you are calling `strcmp()`.  Also, please turn on compiler warnings as this will help you in the long run.

Comment: Using the Arduino IDE, not sure how/if you can do that. I'll update my post to include your suggestion.

Comment: That's not how you use `strcmp`.

Comment: file->preferences->compiler warnings

Comment: Did you look up the API for `strcmp`? Reference can be found here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

strcmp takes two arguments both are `char *` (pointer to a char), you are supplying it with a boolean expression that boils down to a `bool`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When printed, data->value() prints what I expect it to, but when I
>   compare it like this data->value() == "OPEN" it doesn't work. What is
>   the right way to do this, and why isn't the above working?

strcmp takes two arguments both are char * (pointer to a char), you are supplying it with a boolean expression that boils down to a bool

Reference for strcmp can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)

Assuming that `AdafruitIO_Data` is as defined [here](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_IO_Arduino/blob/master/src/AdafruitIO_Data.h) and that you've included `string.h`

```
void handleMessage(AdafruitIO_Data *data) {
  Serial.printf("\nreceived <- %s", data->value());
  if (!strcmp(data->value(), "OPEN")) {
    Serial.printf("\nIt worked!");
  }
}
```

Comment: I had tried this (see my above revision) and it didn't work, it gave me the error (also in the above revision to my question)

Comment: No. You didn't try this. You tried this: `strcmp(data->value() == "OPEN")`

Comment: I'm going to include my comment to your question in my answer for clarity

Comment: You were right! It compiled and now works as expected. Thank you for your patience and pragmatism.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Right. I've fixed it.